# Dynamically changing pictures based on text input

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a webpage at the moment where I am converting temperature to Fahrenheit from Celsius and vice versa. While doing that if the temperature is in a certain degree I need to display a picture and if it is in a different range I need to display another picture(and one more time). I have got the right picture displaying at the right time, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the pictures to switch, and instead they just continually add up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function convertTemp(fAfter) 
{
 var c = document.getElementById('c'), f = document.getElementById('f');
 var fAfter;
 var cAfter
 if(c.value != '') 
 {
  f.value = (c.value * 9 / 5 + 32);
  fAfter = (c.value * 9 / 5 + 32);
  c.value = c.value;
  return fAfter;
 }
 else  
 {
    c.value = ((f.value - 32) * 5 / 9);
    f.value = f.value;
    fAfter = f.value;
    return fAfter;
 }


}
function changePicture()
{

    var A = convertTemp();
    if (A > 50)
        {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = "warm.gif";
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
        else if (A < 50 & A > 32)
        {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = "cool.gif";
            document.body.appendChild(img);         
        }
            else
            {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = "cold.gif";
                document.body.appendChild(img);     
            }
}
function clearBoth()
{
 var c = document.getElementById('c');
 c.value = '';

    var f =document.getElementById('f');
    f.value= '';
}


var button = document.getElementById("convert");

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input placeholder = "Celsius" id="c" onclick='clearBoth()' >&#176C</br>
<input placeholder = "Fahrenheit" id="f" onclick='clearBoth()' >&#176F</br>
<button type="button" id="convert" onclick="convertTemp() & changePicture()">Convert</button>
</body>
<p>

</p>
</html>
```

Comment: just change the `src` attribute of the image tag. `appendChild` won't work for you.

Comment: @TandyRayes - Further to what Ashad said, you may just put an img element in the html and give it an id so you can easily find it later with getElementById.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `img` that is available on the global scope and change it's `src` attribute according to the input value. Initially you can hide the image.

***HTML :***

```
<body>
    <input placeholder = "Celsius" id="c" onclick='clearBoth()' >&#176C</br>
    <input placeholder = "Fahrenheit" id="f" onclick='clearBoth()' >&#176F</br>
    <img src="" id="tempImage"/>
    <button type="button" id="convert">Convert</button>
</body>
```

***javaScript :***

```
var img = document.getElementById("tempImage");
img.style.display = 'none';

function convertTemp(fAfter) 
{
 var c = document.getElementById('c'), f = document.getElementById('f');
 var fAfter;
 var cAfter
 if(c.value != '') 
 {
  f.value = (c.value * 9 / 5 + 32);
  fAfter = (c.value * 9 / 5 + 32);
  c.value = c.value;
  return fAfter;
 }
 else  
 {
    c.value = ((f.value - 32) * 5 / 9);
    f.value = f.value;
    fAfter = f.value;
    return fAfter;
 }


}
function changePicture()
{
    var A = convertTemp();
    img.style.display = '';    
    if (A > 50)
        {
            img.src = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-I5le-iONsuc/UDwY0gx6LMI/AAAAAAAAAnk/2VVq3KX7e2I/s1600/600px-Capital_C.png";
        }
        else if (A < 50 & A > 32)
        {
            img.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/148af423ee41cdb24507f372f95bd4d0/wuvn5qh/ovFmzk9sh/tumblr_static_f-word-1ha91xq.png";       
        }
            else
            {
                img.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/148af423ee41cdb24507f372f95bd4d0/wuvn5qh/ovFmzk9sh/tumblr_static_f-word-1ha91xq.png";    
            }
}
function clearBoth()
{
 var c = document.getElementById('c');
 c.value = '';

    var f =document.getElementById('f');
    f.value= '';
}


var button = document.getElementById("convert");
button.onclick = changePicture;
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/tmmzhq4c/)

Comment: that gets an error of cannot read property "appendChild" of null on line 6.is appendchild the right syntax here?

Comment: There's no such error I found in the fiddle by inspecting it. Where are you getting the error?

Comment: @TandyRayes, You can also go with another solution. Keep an `img` element in your markup and hide it. Then when click event for convert is fired make the image visible. Try the updated answer.

Comment: I found the error just by opening up the webpage and using the source debugger. And with that code I get an error stating cannot read property 'style' null

Comment: Ok I got it. You'r script starts to find something that's not even there. That means your script starts working before your DOM is loaded. So put your code inside `window.onload = function(){ // here }; `. In that case your script will execute after DOM is loaded.

Comment: so put everything inside <script> in that function?

Comment: Yes. If you want to execute your script after your DOM is loaded.

Comment: okay ya that worked, but now my clearBoth function isn't working properly. do I need to take that one out f the window.onload? edit: yes I do thank you so much for your help.